# How to use case and order by in Nhibernate?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, sql-order-by, case, queryover

I need to order result in DB table `ChargeOperations` in **my own direction** by `typeId`.
The SQL request is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ChargeOperations co
LEFT JOIN ShadowChargeOperations sco ON sco.ChargeOperationId=co.Id
-- just exclude some extra data.
WHERE sco.Id IS NULL
ORDER BY
 CASE co.TypeId
  WHEN 1 THEN 3   -- this is my order, which is different from id of type and can change
  WHEN 2 THEN 1
  WHEN 3 THEN 2
  ELSE 4
 END,
 co.TypeId,
 co.CalculationAmount
```

So, please, can you give me an example of how can I create this construction.

```
CASE co.TypeId 
  WHEN 1 THEN 3   -- this is my order, which is different from id of type and can change
  WHEN 2 THEN 1
  WHEN 3 THEN 2
  ELSE 4
```

with QueryOver.

Comment: is `TypeId` the discriminator value? do you need Paging?

Comment: I don't know you meaning as discriminator value. TypeId is a field for sorting. I don't need Paging or smth else. I know how to create it with HQL, but we use queryOver...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it using the `Projections.Conditional`, for sample:

```
ChargeOperation itemAlias = null;

var result = 
    session.QueryOver<ChargeOperation>(() => itemAlias)
            .Where ( /*your conditions*/)
            .OrderBy(Projections.Conditional(
                        Restrictions.Where(() => itemAlias.TypeId == 1),
                        Projections.Constant(3),                                
                    Projections.Conditional(
                        Restrictions.Where(() => itemAlias.TypeId == 2),
                        Projections.Constant(1),
                    Projections.Conditional(
                        Restrictions.Where(() => itemAlias.TypeId == 3),
                        Projections.Constant(2),
                        )
                    )           
                )                           
            ).Asc
            .ThenBy(x => x.TypeId)
            .ThenBy(x => x.CalculationAmount)
        .List();
```

Comment: even it's very old questions, let it be the answer :) I just can't check it.